# How do i make the evenly spread elements in my nav bar not touch the edges of the page?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a resizable navigation bar that will evenly spread the elements across the width of the page. The right more element in the nav sits very close to the end of the page, while the left most element has a nice margin.
How do i make the right most element have a margin from the right, the same way the left most element has a margin from the left?

http://jsfiddle.net/td5rt3or/1/

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BASIC SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR STAFF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
text-align: justify;
min-width: 500px;
}
#nav:after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}

#nav li {
margin-top: 2%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the ul a max-width of 95%, then use margin: 0 auto to center it :

```
#nav {
  max-width:95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The margin you have at the moment is actually padding. Add padding: 0 to the ul to remove it :

```
#nav {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zko26qxu/